# how to be sure that ExecuteScriptAsync is executed in CefSharp

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cefsharp

I am using [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) component in a Windows Forms C# application.

I load my page in the chromium browser and once loaded, I click a button in it using `ExecuteScriptAsync` and close the form.

The code executes normally, but since this happens very quickly, how can I be sure that the button in the page is really clicked?

here is my code:

```
private void OnLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (!args.IsLoading)
    {
        chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('myButton').click();");
        form1.Close();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's already mentioned in documentations, when you use [`ExecuteScriptAsync`](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/Overload_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_ExecuteScriptAsync.htm), the script will be executed asynchronously, and the method therefore returns before the script has actually been executed.

Instead of `ExecuteScriptAsync` which returns immediately, use `EvaluateScriptAsync`and await the call.

If you use [`EvaluateScriptAsync`](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/Overload_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_EvaluateScriptAsync.htm), the script will be executed asynchronously and the method returns a Task encapsulating the response from the script.

**Example**

1. Create a Windows Forms Application.
2. Using Configuration Manager or from Debug Toolbar set the configuration to either x64 or x86 [image].
3. Install [CefSharp.WinForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms) NuGet package.
4. Handle the `Load` event of the form using the following code:

   ```
   ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://www.google.com");
       browser.LoadingStateChanged += async (obj, args) =>
       {
           if (!args.IsLoading)
           {
               await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("alert(Math.sin(Math.PI/2));");
               this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
               {
                   this.Close();
               }));
           }
       };
       this.Controls.Add(browser);
   }
   ```

   Make sure you include the usings:

   ```
   using CefSharp;
   using CefSharp.WinForms;
   ```
5. Run the application and you will see the form will be closed after showing the alert, however if you use `ExecuteScriptAsync`, the form will be closed immediately and you may not see the alert.

Comment: Thanks @Reza Aghaei